# Ext grid plugin listeners getting removed when associated grid is destroyed

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

```
var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
clicksToEdit: 2,
listeners: {
    'beforeedit': function (rowIdx, colIdx) {

    },

    'validateedit': function (editor, e) {            
}
```

});

I have created a cell editing plugin like above and attached it to my grid.

```
 var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                            width: width,
                            height: height,
                            frame: true,
            plugins: [cellEditing]
```

The problem is when i destroy my grid using Ext.getCmp('GridId').destroy(); the plugin's listeners are getting removed.What can I do to reconfigure the plugin as it was before?

Comment: This does not answer your question but is an FYI related to a strange scenario you might encounter after you destroy and recreate the gridpanel again. We encountered a lot of problems after we recreated the gridpanel, the gridpanel would vanish whilst editing a cell..turned out that the gridpanel destroy does not always destroy the listeners,  our solution was to go up to the container level and use the remove [http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-remove]  against the gridpanel, the remove traversed into the gridpanel and removed the listeners  correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create & assign the plugin dynamically.

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    width: width,
    height: height,
    frame: true,
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2,
            listeners: {
                beforeedit: function (rowIdx, colIdx) {
                },
                validateedit: function (editor, e) {            
                }
            }
        });
    ]
});
```